# Trying to create an image from DataTask using URLsession not working

Tags: ios, swift

I created a function that would fetch an image from a url and assign it to a variable and it would return that variable as an image. Though it is not return anything and crashing.

```
func downloadImage(imageUrl:String) -> UIImage {
        var imageDownloaded : UIImage?
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration)
        let task = session.dataTask(with: URL(string: imageUrl)!) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                return
            }
            do {
                imageDownloaded = try UIImage(data: data!)
            } catch {
                print("Fail")
            }
        }
        task.resume()
        return imageDownloaded! //Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to forcefully unwrap the variable 'imageDownloaded' at the point it is not having any value (i.e. nil). This is happening because downloading of image data is taking time.

To fix this, you should use completion handler

```
func downloadImage(imageUrl:String, @escaping completionHandler: (UIImage?)->()) {
    var imageDownloaded : UIImage?
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration)
    let task = session.dataTask(with: URL(string: imageUrl)!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            return
        }
        do {
            imageDownloaded = try UIImage(data: data!)
            completionHandler(imageDownloaded!)
        } catch {
            print("Fail")
            completionHandler(nil)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: may I ask can you explain briefly what this escaping completion handler does in this case? and how do I declare my method now?

Comment: Completion handlers are typically a block of code which gets executed after a certain task has been completed. They can be either non escaping, or escaping. In your case, because you are making a web service call, and we want our completion block to be executed after the response from server, we declare it with the annotation '@escaping'. However, Xcode takes care of this. If you do not write @escaping, xcode will make you write it.

Comment: To call the method, just start writing the name of method and follow autocomplete by xcode. When you press tab, the second argument i.e. completion block will be highlighted, hit enter. Xcode will automatically write the completion block for you.